# How to xcopy all folders starting with string in depth 1?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, xcopy

I'm running xcopy within a Jenkins build.

I have the following directory structure:

```
Ensure\
  a
    Web_ERP
  b
  c
    Web_ERP
  Web_ERP
  Web_ERP_Claims
  Web_ERP_Finance
```

I'm trying to copy all folders which start with "Web_ER*" under Ensure (depth=1) to my current workspace.

```
node () {
    stage ('Setup') {
        deleteDir()
        bat '''
            IF NOT EXIST c:\\deploy mkdir c:\\deploy
            cd ..\\Ensure
            xcopy Web_ER* "%WORKSPACE%" /e
        '''
    }
}
```

In reality, all the folders which start with Web_ER* are being copied along with Web_ER* folders which reside under folders a and c.

I want only Web_ER* folders which reside under Ensure to be copied along with their content.

I've tried the following switches with xcopy: /i /e /s /m but I get the same result every time.

**Edit #1:**

@magoo when I run the command you gave it copies all the files which are under each one of the Web_ER* folders without the folders themselves, I want to copy all the folders strating with "Web_ER*" with all their subdirectories to my destination folder.
Following your example I've also tried:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad web_er*') do xcopy ".\\%%a" "%WORKSPACE%" /e /y
```

But to no avail.

In linux for example it's as easy as:

```
cp -R folder/pattern* destination/dir
```

I'm looking for the equivalent command in windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure-Publish>cd ..\Ensure 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>xcopy Web_ER* "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure-Publish"  
0 File(s) copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad web_er*') do xcopy ".\%%a\*" "%WORKSPACE%" /e
```

should accomplish this. Process a directory list in `/b` basic (name-only) form `/ad` of directorynames matching `web_er*` in the current directory, and apply each name found in turn to `%%a`; then `xcopy` all of the files.

Comment: Not sure whether the OP wants the `Web_ER*` folders to be copied as well, but if so, you'd need to include them in the copy destination (and to add option `/i` then)...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following powershell command:

```
Get-childitem | where {$_.name -like "Web_ER*"} | copy-item -recurse -destination ..\Ensure-Publish -force
```